# Complex password for laravel user registeration

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I want to validate entered user password for complex character password,

Is there any package or method for this validation ?

Comment: Surely by using pregmatch, u can check for character types in a given string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this may help a lot to set at client side, or you can create similar at server side for regex pattern.

```
var password = document.getElementById('pswdfield').value;
var validLength = /.{8}/.test(password);
var hasCaps = /[A-Z]/.test(password);
var hasNums = /\d/.test(password);
var hasSpecials = /[~!,@#%&_\$\^\*\?\-]/.test(password);

var isValid = validLength && hasCaps && hasNums && hasSpecials;
```

in $rules validation array add

```
'password'=>'required|regex:/^.*(?=.{3,})(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[\d\X])(?=.*[!$#%]).*$/'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use package give a try with this package.

https://packagist.org/search/?q=password-strength
https://github.com/schuppo/PasswordStrengthPackage

And if you want to accomplish that using regular expression check this question. Here you'll find a detailed answer.

[Laravel password validation rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31539727/laravel-password-validation-rule)