# Strong passwords validation laravel

Tags: php, regex, laravel, phpunit, laravel-7

So before any one shuts this down, **I am referencing an answer and asking a question here**.

So the question I have is I want a strong password validation for laravel, something that includes 10 character, numbers, upper lower case, so on and so forth.

I found it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31549892/1270259

The problem is, this regex looks off:

```
/^.*(?=.{3,})(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[\d\X])(?=.*[!$#%]).*$/
```

And since I am not good with regex I thought I would ask how can I fix it such that it validates:

- Must be 10 characters long
- Must contain upper and lower case
- Must contain at least one number
- Must contain at least one special character.

I feel like they were close in the answer. When this is run against github actions the error that comes back is `preg_match(): Compilation failed: escape sequence is invalid in character class at offset 46`.

Any thoughts as too how I can make this work for Laravel 7 to match the above constraints?

Comment: Instead of having one regex for all your requirements why don't you validate against one requirement at a time. Not only will it simplify your regex to something understandable for you, it will also allow you to respond with a relevant message on failure because you'll know which part of the validation it failed.

Comment: Having double checked the thread you linked, checkout the answer with 17 upvotes, that's exactly what I was referring to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the principle of contrast:

```
^
(?=[^a-z]*[a-z]) # ensure one lower case letter
(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z]) # ensure one upper case letter
(?=\D*\d)        # ensure a digit
(?=[^!@?]*[!@?]) # special chars
.{10,}           # at least 10 characters long
$
```

You can extend the special char section, of course.
See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/1NA8uS/1).