# Is it possible to check if a user's password matches a specific string in laravel-php?

Tags: php, laravel, if-statement, passwords

I need to check every user on my laravel project to see if their password is unsafe.
For example, check if their password is simply "password", if so i would change it and send it to their email.

Is it possible?

Comment: This should be done when the User is registering. If you didn't have a Password Complexity rule in place previously, you can simply bulk email everyone to let them know they should consider changing it now that you do. If you're properly `Hash`-ing Passwords in Laravel, then you would have to try a bunch of "weak" combinations against them using `Hash::check()`, which is insanity beyond a handful of Users. If you're not hashing password, then you have a much bigger issue.

Comment: You can also shim in a check during user log-in and either suggest that they change it, or force it. Also, do not email passwords as email is _wildly_ insecure. If anything, invalidate the password and send them instructions on the password reset workflow.

Answer (score -2):

This post has a regex that checks for a safe password
[Laravel password validation rule](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31539727/20351425)

**Your regular expression would look like this:**

```
^.*(?=.{3,})(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[\d\x])(?=.*[!$#%]).*$
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).